# Синхронный захват видео с нескольких камер

Tags: directshow, видео, c++

**Вводные:** есть несколько веб-камер. В Windows они представлены как Video Capture Sources.

**Задача:** получить синхронную (плюс-минус один кадр) запись видеопотоков в файлы. 
То есть нужно, чтобы файлы начинались синхронно и не разбегались по мере проигрывания.

Как я понимаю, при записи с нескольких камер для каждой камеры нужно построить свой граф захвата. Есть ли штатные средства в Directshow синхронизировать графы? Можно ли обеспечить синхронное начало записи для нескольких графов?

Если начало синхронизировать невозможно, то есть ли способы хотя бы узнать timestamp у первых кадров в каждой записи, чтобы потом вручную выровнять их по времени?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно поможет создание отдельного фильтра, имеющего входные и выходные пины видеопотоков равно по количеству последних. Этот фильтр должен пропускать кадры во врайтеры синхронно, то есть исключительно тогда, когда на всех входах будут готовы новые видеокадры. Возможно потребуется создать FIFO-буферы видеокадров для каждого из потоков, так как скорость захвата видео в одних может превышать скорость захвата в других.

Answer (score 0):

Полученные кадры имеют соответствующую информацию с меткой времени. Соответственно можно, конечно же, сопоставлять их и иметь информацию об их положении друг относительно друга на временной оси.

Более того, оба метода будут работать: когда каждый видео источник генерирует кадры в своем графе (и относительно своей точки отсчета времени), так и когда все видео источники находятся в одном графе и ведут отсчет вместе.

Получить синхронный отсчет времени не сильно напрягаясь можно только в случае общего графа. Запустить разные графы синхронно вообще говоря нельзя, но с помощью [некоторой уловки](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1300818/868014) можно это сделать довольно неплохо. По-хорошему видео в независимых графах все равно придется приводить к общему знаменателю сопоставлением относительного времени кадра и времени начала сессии.